# how to output compiler errors into a file using Visual Studio 2010 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file, debugging

I'm trying to find a way to print out compiler error information into a file just like the way the .log files are written. I've looked in many places for help, but came up short. Anyone have any ideas on how it can be done?

Comment: What language? What compiler?

Comment: I just edited the title for clarity. I'm working with the 32-bit version of VS 2010. Running on Windows 7. I'm compiling C++ code. Not sure what the compiler is..It's just what you get when you download VS 2010 express.

Comment: You could build using `nmake` instead. It works on the command line and you have more options in directing the build and its output.

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with VS2008, and I am not sure if it can help for VS2010.

For VS2008, Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Build Log File.